# How to send non-HTML mail from Apple Mail?

Tags: mail.app

Can someone help me to find out how to send non-HTML mail from Apple Mail client?

Comment: what is non-HTML ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 non-html is "plain text".  When you do View > Message > Raw Source, you do not see any html codes anywhere.

Comment: Non-html is the default mode for Apple Mail as far as I know.  You have to do something special to send html.

Comment: @Tom Gewecke, the default is "Rich Text".

Comment: @Tom Gewecke, as I've previously said, the default **is** "RichText" and on a clean install of OS X and upon first opening of Mail.app, creating an account and new message without applying any formatting it shows `Content-Type: text/html` and has `<html> ... </html>` tags around what I've written when viewing the raw source.  Additionally the default "Message Format" under Preferences is set to "Rich Text" and the "Format" menu shows "Make Plain Text.  Therefore everything points to the default being "Rich Text" (HTML).

Comment: With Rich Text as the chosen format in Preferences if you type a simple email it sends it as plain text. But as soon as you start doing anything more complex than simple text it sends it as Rich Text (i.e. HTML).

Comment: @Tom Gewecke, No sig, no attachment and all I typed was "This is a test message without formatting" and it's HTML.  That said I'm not going to argue this anymore!

Comment: @user3439894  On my 10.10.3, when I duplicate your settings and text, I get only a plain text message without any html in the source.  I have had the same result with every version of OS X since Tiger.  I wonder if there is some other difference between our systems, like the OS language, which could cause this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alternatives are described as Plain Text or Rich Text - however I am reliably informed that 'Rich Text' is, in fact HTML.
(Thanks to @TomGewecke for correcting me on that in comments)

Swap permanently in Prefs > Composing, or as a one-off in Format Menu, last item, or  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd> 
  <kbd>T</kbd>

To prevent replying in HTML to an HTML mail, also uncheck 'Use the same Message format...'

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Rich Text" is in fact just Apple's name for HTML.  You can see the html content designation and all the html codes by doing View > Message > Raw Source

Comment: Ah, OK. Thanks @TomGewecke I'll tweak my answer to suit. ty again.